# Component to setup plug in params

Tags: joomla

I would like to know if it's possible to pass params to some plugins using a component.

My 'Application' contains 2 plugins (system and content) and there are a few params which are the same in the 2 plug-ins (eg : Facebook API key).

So I was thiking about making a component to configure the plugin params, so there is only one configuration for the user.

Is is possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [JComponentHelper::getParams](http://docs.joomla.org/JComponentHelper%3a%3agetParams/11.1).

In your plugins you could use:

```php
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_yourcomponent');
```